# How to access items of jagged array in CLI-C++

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to use a jagged array (array of array) of double with CLI-C++, but I don't know how to access the items. The last line of my code produces the errormessage: "cannot be called with the given argument list" (Visual Studio 2017). What would be the correct way to do this?

```
List<List<double>^> ^lld = gcnew List<List<double>^>();
lld->Add(gcnew List<double>);
lld[0]->Add(17.4);
double d = lld[0][0];
```

Comment: Please use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  The workaround with parentheses will keep you going.

Answer (score 1):

Using parenthesis should give the compiler the appropriate hint to use the operator[].

```
double d = (lld[0])[0];
```

Comment: Of course I did try this. The funny thing is: while in the code editor of the visual studio the error message still appears, it compiles without an error. I found that the original text behaves the same: no error when compiling. Ususlly I don't compile when there are still errors marked in the editor.

Comment: Than this is a bug in the parser. You should report it.